# getline() does not return the last newline

Tags: c++, linux, newline, getline

I am using g++ on linux but encountered a strange problem. When trying to read a file which ends on an empty line (just a '\n'), then getline() just skips that line. I also tried to read it as binary but that gives the same result. On windows I am able to detect if it has an empty line or not. On linux not so much. How can I detect it on linux?

Thanks!

EDIT:
I get an error box when trying to post my code here:
"Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon."

But anyway it is the same as [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) under the section **Text files** where getline() is used.

EDIT 2:
Tried to remove tabs etc, but still get error box. I tried to surround it with:
< pre >< code >...< /code >< /pre >

EDIT 3:

```
std::ifstream inFile(fileName);
if(!inFile)
{
    std::cout << "Cannot open input file" << std::endl;
    return;
}

std::string str;
while (getline(inFile, str))
{
    std::cout << "#" << str << "#" << std::endl;
}
inFile.close();
```

Okay, had to select all the text then Ctrl+K.

EDIT 4:
TextFile.txt

```
}\n
```

Then the output is:

```
#}#
```

If I change the file to:

```
}\n
\n
```

Then the output is:

```
#}#
```

But I was expecting:

```
#}#
##
```

Comment: Do you perhaps have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you can show us? Please edit your question to include it then. Also show us some sample input together with the expected and actual output.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the code and a small example of the file that you are trying to read?

Comment: It seems `getline` reads empty lines in the middle and at the end of a stream: http://ideone.com/R5Du9L

Comment: Did you try marking the code and pressing C-k? Like the error message you are quoting says?

Comment: I've tested your code (that is, pretty much your code, as it's a bit incomplete) and it works for me as expected (both with UNIX-style EOLs and DOS-style EOLs). Are you sure your `getline` is `std::getline`?

Comment: @vencik Yes it is std::getline(). I don't know how to solve this. I am trying to make a simple text editor that is cross platform, then fumbled into this little problem. Perhaps I should just ignore it but this makes me wounder about if the standard library isn't really OS independent. Anyway thanks.